# Substituting filter with reduce for counting objects within range

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

I'm currently using this logic to filter out an array of objects within a date range and get a total count of the objects within that range.

```
const extractInRange = function (range, payload) {
    const start = new Date(range.startDate)
    const end = new Date(range.endDate)
    let dateRangeCount = 0
    payload.filter(item => {
        let date = new Date(item.createDate)
        if (date >= start && date <= end) {
            dateRangeCount++
        }
    })
    return dateRangeCount
}
```

I want to substitute my **filter** logic with **reduce** specifically and I'm not sure how I should proceed.
I do know how to use **reduce** on arrays but the addition of **start** and **end** is causing some issues for me.

Comment: Reduce passes what you previously return to the next iteration so either return prev+1 or just prev .reduce((a,b)=>a+withinRange(b),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `let dateRangeCount = 0`, and you want iterations to conditionally increment that variable, so let that be your accumulator. Inside the callback, add to the accumulator if the conditions are met:

```
const extractInRange = function(range, payload) {
  const start = new Date(range.startDate);
  const end = new Date(range.endDate);
  return payload.reduce((dateRangeCount, item) => {
    const date = new Date(item.createDate);
    return dateRangeCount + (date >= start && date <= end);
  }, 0);
}
```

Here, the `dateRangeCount` will be a number, and `(date >= start && date <= end)` will be a boolean, so if the condition succeeds on an iteration, it'll return `dateRangeCount + 1`, else it'll return `dateRangeCount`. The return value will be the new accumulator (the `dateRangeCount`) for the next iteration.